# ExpressionEngine missing channel entries

Tags: tags, expressionengine, missing-data, channel

I am working on a new web app which is based in ExpressionEngine and for the most part I am basing the content on channel entries. However I am experiencing some very weird issues with the exp channel entries tag in that it is not returning all relevant entries each time. I can't figure out what's going on with it as the entries are definitely available when viewing them in the control panel, and they will also show up as requested in my template, but sometimes they just disappear and/or are not processed properly. This is the case for large and small sets of entries also, ranging from 3 channel entries which fit the criteria specified within the exp tag to 500 entries.

Any thoughts or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conor, so you have access to http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com? Can you post EE questions there? If you need an invite, let me know.

Comment: MediaGirl, I think the problem is solved now. I'm pretty sure that some of the entries were being marked off as having expired for some reason. Maybe a separate plugin was interfering with the status of the channel entries or something along those lines

Comment: Great! FYI, the EE Stack Exchange site is now in public beta. You can post future EE questions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a number of things going on here so here are some things to look at, just in case;

If the entries have entry dates in the future - you'll need your channel entries tag to have the parameter show_future_entries = "yes"

Likewise if the entries are closed, or expired, you'll need to add show="open|closed"

Are you looking at a particular category and these entries aren't assigned to the category?

Are you looking at a particular category but have exlcuded category data from the entries tag

Are you retrieving more than 100 entries? There is a default limit of 100 entries returned unless you specify a limit parameter.